# Build Django Model for a users' job history repeating segment of a webapp

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm setting up a Django model for a webapp, however my **current model will no longer sufice** for users. How could I extend the **Experience model** to accurately capture the requirements for work experience history?

My webapp is a tutoring app, it should get details about the work history or experiences for a new tutor. So, a tutor with 3 previous work experience would need to enter 3 different work experience history.

Currently, my webapp tracks just ***1 to 3*** work experience history (as seen in the **Experience model** code below), but I need to to capture use cases for a tutor with say ***n work experience history***.

Tutor model (for reference)

```
class Tutor(models.Model):
   """Model representing a tutor."""
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
   phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   ...
```

Experience model (where I need to capture n work experience history)

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    """Model representing a tutor's experience."""
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    organization_one = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    job_position_one = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    organization_two = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    job_position_two = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    organization_three = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    job_position_three = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

If I continue with this above model, I would have to create n columns to capture n work experience history. I feel there is a better approach but I don't know it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is actually correct to a certain degree. Here's what you should use:

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    """Model representing a tutor's experience."""
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    job_position = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you would create additional positions with:

```
tutor.experience_set.create(
    organization='org1',
    position='position1',
)
tutor.experience_set.create(
    organization='org2',
    position='position2',
)
tutor.experience_set.create(
    organization='org3',
    position='position3',
)
```

Comment: Thanks @schillingt, with your answer would this mean having 'org1', 'org2', 'org3', 'position1', 'position2', and 'position3' as individual table coulmns? If yes, I'd prefer not having to list it that way since I have to account for a Tutor that might have more than 3 work experience history. Just like Linkedin could allow you to keep entering different institutions attended.

Comment: No it would not. Add a test model and try it out in a shell.

Comment: So did that and getting an AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'experience_set' when I tried to makemigrations.

Comment: I don't know how you got that error. `experience_set` is the default `related_name` property, so it should exist. I have a feeling you're doing something different than I expected. Try reviewing the Django docs around ForeignKeys. Relationship overview: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ Details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Thanks @schillingt, that first link clearly explained my requirement which is in line with your answer.